# Dual of l_inf space of bounded sequences in R

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

So, I was searching for ways of finding the dual of $l_\infty(\mathbb{R})$, (the space of bounded sequences of real numbers, under the infinity norm, i.e.,
$$||x|| = sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |x_n|.$$

I tried to approach the same way I did for $l_1, l_p, c_0$ and other similar spaces, however, I was not able to find any Schauder Basis for $l_\infty$. So I started searching, but I didn't find anything concrete about it. Does anybody knows an explicit "calculation" of $(l_\infty)^*$, or a book or paper that shows a way to obtain it?

Comment: By the way, spaces with a Schauder basis must be separable, and $\ell^\infty$ isn't.